# How do I set up the ARChon custom runtime on Chromebook?

Tags: android, skype, google-chrome-extensions, chromebook

Most of my friends use Skype, and I wanted to use it on my Chromebook. If was searching for how to install it, and I found [this article.](http://www.howtogeek.com/199857/how-to-use-skype-on-your-chromebook/) I followed the steps in the article and on it's linked pages, and installed the ARChon custom runtime. However, when I attempted to run the demo app with it, it refused to run, and instead displayed a window with only the app icon. How do I fix this?

Details:

Chromebook:

HP 14" Chromebook

Version 40.0.2214.91 beta

Platform 6457.78.0 (Official Build) beta-channel nyan_blaze

Firmware Google_Nyan_Blaze.5771.63.0

ARChon Custom Runtime 1.2 - x86_32 38.4410.120.43

Comment: I don't think the run-time is ready for prime-time at the moment. The quickest, least painful ways to chat through Skype on a Chromebook today:

1. Use Outlook.com (the website, not the desktop software).

2. Install the Web Messenger extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-messenger/hicmdbckjafmndeclhgnkokigkedpenm